# Retrieve table data from stored procedure using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework v6. I have a stored procedure as shown below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCountryList] 
(
    @CustomerName VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @SearchCriteria VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

        SELECT CountryID, CountryName FROM dbo.Table1 
        WHERE CustomerName = @CustomerName AND CountryName = @SearchCriteria
    END
```

Now I have a model class

```
public class CountryName
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to get the result of the `SELECT` query in a `List<CountryName>` type

```
List<CountryName> countryList = null;

using (DbEntities dbContext = new DbEntities())
{
    countryList = //my code to collect the result
}
```

Well, I could have run a LINQ to SQL directly on the table but unfortunately my requirement in to get the data from stored procedure. So, how can I do it?

Comment: Check out the first part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75465142/8644294

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You need to Import the stored procedure as a Function. Right-click on the workspace area of your Entity model and choose `Add -> Function Import`.
2. In the Add Function Import dialog, enter the name you want your stored procedure to be referred to in your model for example `GetCountryListSP`, choose your procedure from the drop down list, and choose the return value of the procedure to be `Entities` and choose `CountryName` from the drop down list.
3. Then in the code:

   ```
   var result = db.GetCountryListSP();//Send parameters too
   ```

   With this approach you prevent returning `-1` of the stored procedure. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140774/getting-data-from-stored-procedure-with-entity-framework) post for more details about stored procedure problem with Entity Framework.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it without importing. Something like that:

```
var countryList = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<CountryName>("[GetCountryList]").ToList();
```

EntityFramework sometimes won't recognize or import SPs ))) So, that's why I saving my hours with this snippet.

Comment: i used this but some time it does not work , the ef does not execute the stored procedure on live environment but when i execute proc on sql management studio or in my local visual studio then it works does it a some kind of bug in ef?

Comment: I now changed my code to what @S.Akbari suggested, db.procedure(); and its working uptill now , i am also monitoring it if any thing wrong happens.