# geting null value from stored procedure in MVC4 razor in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, razor

Here i am using MVC4 razor and stored procedure.Here i am trying to retrieve userid and usertype from sp (retrieving as a objec) ,but i am getting null value for tabledata variable .How could i get userid and usertype for that particular username and password,please help me i am new to MVC

Homecontroller.cs

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(logintable p)
    {
        OnlineAppraisalEntities db = new OnlineAppraisalEntities();

        logintable tabledata = new logintable();

        tabledata = db.sp_Userlogindata(p.Username, p.Password);

        return View(p);
    }
```

Stored procedure

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Userlogindata]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

@Username varchar(30),
@Password varchar(30)
AS

BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select Usertype,UserID from logintable where Username=@Username and     Password=@Password

END
```

Comment: Your `tabledata` variable may contain the data but you don't do anything with it (all you doing is returning the original data you posted)

Comment: Also You need to Import the stored procedure as a Function. Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/a/32359095/2946329

Comment: @Stephen Muecke here all i need is to get userid and usertype to valid username and password,then on getting this i will pass this to other actionresult in same controller as a parameter.