# Entity Framework database first approach having string as return type for stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I working on an MVC product using Database first entity framework approach, I added a few stored procedure to the EDM, but some are returning string instead of the model type. I have deleted the model.edmx, removed the connection string from the web.config file and re- added model1.edmx file to the project, yet, some still have string as return type, I have also created a viewmodel class and use it in place of the string, yet no luck. I want to be able to add procedure to return type of the model.

Stored Procedure in `Model1.Context` class:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<string> PreLoadWorkflowType()
{            
    return((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("PreLoadWorkflowType");
}
```

I want the generated stored procedure to look like this instead:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<PreLoadWorkflowType> PreLoadWorkflowType()
{               return((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<PreLoadWorkflowType>("PreLoadWorkflowType");
}
```

I have been adding stored procedure to the EDM file all the while, i have not experience this before, I will appreciate assistance from anyone who had experienced and resolved this.

Stored Procedure:

```
USE [databsename]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[PreLoadWorkflowType]    Script Date: 
1/30/2018 11:46:15 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PreLoadWorkflowType]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
--@RequestType varchar(10),
--@WorkFlowType varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select distinct workflow_type  AS WorkflowType from V_ui_View  where 
workflow_type is not null 
END
```

Where `V_ui_View` is a view

Comment: It would help to actually show the definition of `PreLoadWorkflowType` in the database. Note that stored procedures cannot return anything but a single `INT` -- the result set of a stored procedure can be mapped differently, though, and scalar-valued functions can return any type.

Comment: Thanks, i have added the stored procedure to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32359095/2946329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F-ES Sitecore a senior Developer in another platform posted an answer to this, and it resolved the issue. Check the solution below:

In the model browser select your SP and in the properties window click "Return Type" then click the ellipses button to open the "Edit Function Import" dialog.

In the "Returns a collection of" if you want the SP to return instances of an existing entity then select Entities and the relevant one. If the data doesn't match an existing entity then select "Complex", click "Get Column Information", then click "Create New Complex Type" and it'll create a class for you with the relevant properties and amend the code so it now returns ObjectResult

Comment: Thanks. For more details check this link http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2009/03/13/mapping-stored-procedure-results-to-a-custom-entity-in-entity-framework/

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting only one column value from statement which has varchar/string type, so this ObjectResult returns String.
I have checked that if selecting multiple column value in select statement then it returns ObjectResult and you can usee only required column value